# $\cos(\pi/6 *2\pi)$ in radians isn't equal to $\cos(30*360)$ in degrees why?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I put $\cos(\pi/6*2\pi)$ in radians mode on my calculator and i get $-0.9890273166$ and then I put $\cos(30*360)$ in degrees mode and get $1$, the answer is the complete opposite of what it should be and in case if you don't know $\pi/6*2\pi$ converted to degrees equals $30*360$, so I really need an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: $\cos\left(\frac \pi 6 \times 2 \pi\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{3}\right)=-0.989027$ is correct. I suppose that is not what you want to do.

Comment: $\frac \pi 6$ in radians is 30 degrees. No need to multiply with $2 \pi$ or $360$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for Radian-Degree conversion is$${\theta \text{ in Radians}\over \pi}={\theta \text{ in Degrees}\over 180}$$so you may write$$\theta \text{ in Degrees}={180\over \pi}\theta \text{ in Radians}$$so we have$$2\pi\cdot {\pi\over 6}\text{ Rad}=60\pi\text{ Deg}\approx 188.495559 \text{ Deg}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cos$ is periodic with period $360^\circ$. Therefore, yes, $\cos(30\times360^\circ)=\cos(0)=1$.

And if you use your calculator in radians mode, you will get that $\cos(30\times2\pi)=1$, too. But $\frac\pi6\approx0.523599$, and therefore there's no reason why $\cos\left(\frac\pi6\times2\pi\right)$ should be $1$ too. You seem to think that $\frac\pi6=30$, but that is just wrong. What happens is that $\frac\pi6$ radians is equal to $30^\circ$, but this is an equality between *angles*, not between *numbers*.

Comment: If $2\pi$ radians is $360$ degrees, then $\pi$ radians is equivalent to $180$ degrees, and it is correct to sat that $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians equates to $30$ degrees...

Comment: @MRobinson I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're right, but I still don't know why I can't convert pi to 180, looks like I can't do that anymore and have to follow the formula from mostafa

Comment: @ShayanR. But you *can* convert. It turns out that $\pi$ **radians** is equal to $180$ **degrees**. But the *number* $\pi$ is quite different from the number $180$.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't convert degee to radian each term separately, combine them together and then convert into radians, by multiplying with $ \frac{ \pi}{180} $

Your **( $ \frac{ \pi}{6} \cdot 2 \pi $)** is not equal to **30 $ \cdot$360** in degrees.
To convert **30 $ \cdot$360**, i.e. **10800** degrees to radians, you need to multiply it by **$ \frac{ \pi}{180} $**
So, it is equal to **60$ \pi $** radians.

Put **cos(60$ \pi$)** in radians in your calculator, you will get **1.**

Comment: all i think of is pi =180 so then change to degrees. Is that wrong?

Comment: yes. pi in radians is 180 in degrees, pi=180 is definitely wrong (pi=3.14). you need to multiply by pi/180 to convert degree to radian and vice versa.